# ¿Cómo puedo enviar un array desde android con php y despues obtener otro array que proceda de php?

Tags: php, java, android, android-studio, array

Bueno pues como dice en la pregunta quiero enviar un array desde android a php, para que este haga una consulta con esos datos y despues guardar el resultado de esa consulta en un array y enviarlo desde el php a la apk, para que desde la aplicación pueda trabajar con esos datos obtenidos.

Enviar un array desde android a php me funciona utilizando la libreria volley pero no se como enviar un array desde php a android, debido a que usan librerias antiguas y no quiero usarlas

Comment: Hola, considera revisar [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

En si lo que debes hacer es una APIRest que realice lo que necesites, nativamente puedes usar `json_encode($data)` para generar el json y consumirlo en la aplicacion de android ya sea con Volley o Retrofit(Ya es a gustos). Ejemplo

```
function regresarDatosParaAndroid($data)
{
    #Realizas tus operaciones 
    return json_encode($data)
}
```

Lo nativo de PHP aunque sientas que antiguas son standard y son potentes, todo framework de PHP las usa internamente, claro lo optimizan y hacen otra capa de software para que funcionen mejor. Si te interesa hacer rápidamente una APIRest puedes usar LUMEN (https://lumen.laravel.com/) es un framework sencillo y fácil de aprender.
Te recomiendo que busques todo lo referente a la generación de API'S para que veas como funcionan internamente las aplicaciones móviles en cuestion de consumir y enviar datos.

Comment: no entendi casi nada XD, por lo que e estado mirando las apis son como los web services , pero no entiendo en php como le pasas el array a android

Comment: En si no le pasas un Array a android en esencia pasas los datos en algún formato, usualmente Json o XML incluso en una cadena de texto es posible. Ya en android los manipulas para mostrarlos.